# Which is more semantic if I need to choose between <hr> or extra wrapper <div>?

Tags: html, xhtml, semantic-markup

To make a divider in one specific design where I'm working, I need to make a divider between groups of multiple elements. I have only 2 options: either I can wrap elements (inner elements are not same in height) inside a `<div>`, or I can use an `<hr>`.

If I use an extra `div`, it will be only to make a separator.

Which is more semantic, one extra `div` or `hr`?

Comment: Are those elements floated? Are they stacked horizontally? What is below the divider - one element or multiple elements stacked horizontally?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - yes items are floated. Divider is in between jQuery slider and main content area

Comment: When I have multiple floated elements, I wrap them inside a `overflow:auto` DIV. That would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the dividing lines are part of the content, then `<hr>` is definitely the appropriate answer.

However, a dividing line could be considered as a design element, in which case it shouldn't be in the HTML code; design should be done in stylesheets.

So the question is whether the dividing lines you plan to draw are part of the content or the design?

You can answer this question by considering whether removing the dividing lines would affect the content in the same way as removing `<br>` tags would do. Or by considering if you had to give the content to someone else to publish elsewhere, whether you would want to include the dividing lines as part of what you send. If the answer is 'yes', then they are part of your content.

If it's purely a case of it being your page design, then you should use stylesheets to add dividers because although `<hr>` is more semantic, it is only semantically correct if it forms an active part of the content.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Divider are just visual part of design. they are not separating any content As i Think.

Comment: If you're not sure about whether the `<hr>` is semantic (a bit of a gray area), go with the CSS fix.  Less markup to maintain and style usually lends the most flexibility down the road.

Answer (score 2):

You say you can wrap inner elements in a `<div>`, but that the `<div>` would only serve as a separator. If it has inner elements, it seems as though you may be using it to group related content, in which case I would suggest that as the most semantic approach. Otherwise, `<hr>` is your best option.

Comment: @Michael Mior - Thanks for reply +1 . But if i don't need the divider then I don't need the extra `<div>` to group other elements. and Is use of `<hr>` semantically correct?

Comment: What I was getting at is that if the elements you do end up grouping together have some meaningful relationship to each other, than putting them in a `<div>` is highly semantic.

If they aren't, this makes things worse and `<hr>` is more sensible as it's used to define a separation.

Comment: @Michael Mior - OK. But use of `<hr>` is not semantically correct.

Comment: If you look at the W3C definition of `<hr>` in HTML 5, you'll see "In HTML5, the `<hr>` tag displays a horizontal rule, and defines a change in the content." So it is potentially semantically correct depending on your content.

Comment: After seeing your comment on the other answer, it appears that `<hr>` may not be semantically correct in your case.

Comment: In my case Divider is in between jQuery slider and main content area